# DD-WRT Wifidog - Redirect isn't working

Tags: iptables, dd-wrt, hotspot

I have flashed a ASUS AC-RT56U router with DD-WRT version V24-preSP 2201412-22-2014-r25697.
Now I want to make it into a hotspot with wifidog TO PLACE IN A SMALL BUSINESS (FITNESS CENTRE)

I have created my own authentication server, to troubleshoot where it goes wrong. 
When I connect a new wireless device, it doesn't have access to internet, only to the DD-WRT router and the authentication server. When I type an url (like: www.google.com) I don't get redirected to the login page. In my access.log file on the server I only see the DD-wrt router sending ping requests to the server. I have it so my custom authentication server always replies 'Pong'.

I saw there is an bug about this http://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/3344. But it hasn't got any response. This is precisely what happens on my device. When I access http: //routerip:2060 I do get the portal page of my authentication server.

Now I want to know if it is possible to create a iptables rule so all traffic that's not authenticated is redirected to the http: //routerip:2060 page? I guess the rest of the process will work when that redirect works.

This is the diagram how the authentication process of wifidog works. The first redirect is the one that doesn't work.
http://dev.wifidog.org/wiki/doc/developer/FlowDiagram

I don't have any experience modifing iptables rules.

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             dd-wrt           tcp dpt:telnet 
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
WiFiDog_br0_WIFI2Internet  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             123.123.123.123.colo.transip.net 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     gre  --  192.168.128.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.128.0/24     anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 
lan2wan    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
TRIGGER    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            TRIGGER type:in match:0 relate:0 
trigger_out  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain WiFiDog_br0_AuthServers (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logaccept  0    --  anywhere             123.123.123.123.colo.transip.net 

Chain WiFiDog_br0_Global (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain WiFiDog_br0_Known (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logaccept  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain WiFiDog_br0_Locked (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logreject  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain WiFiDog_br0_Unknown (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logaccept  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
logaccept  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 
logaccept  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
logaccept  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps 
logreject  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain WiFiDog_br0_Validate (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logaccept  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain WiFiDog_br0_WIFI2Internet (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
WiFiDog_br0_AuthServers  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
WiFiDog_br0_Locked  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0x254 
WiFiDog_br0_Global  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
WiFiDog_br0_Validate  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0x1 
WiFiDog_br0_Known  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0x2 
WiFiDog_br0_Unknown  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain advgrp_1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_10 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_3 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_4 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_5 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_6 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_7 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_8 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_9 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_10 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_3 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_4 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_5 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_6 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_7 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_8 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_9 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain lan2wan (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain logaccept (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain logreject (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 

Chain trigger_out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug in DD-WRT, which is basically unmaintained and unsupported, and has been for years](https://serverfault.com/questions/666316/dd-wrt-wifidog-redirect-isnt-working#comment813933_666316).

Your options are to use something different that doesn't have this bug (ideally something that's actively developed and maintained), or put up with this bug.

Comment: That is part of the question, how can I circumvent the limitation this bug introduces. I guess with a iptables rule I can still make this work.